# Restarting Azure VM does not fully start services until I log into it

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I have a VM I for deployments using Octopus Deploy. I have it automatically shut down at night.  So in the Auzre Portal, I start the VM and it starts but the webs erver and services I need to not start unless I RDP into the machine.

How can I get the machine to fully startup?

Answer (score 1):

Are the services configured for automatic startup (with no delay)? If yes, there might be a problem with the startup process and you can use event viewer to troubleshoot. You should see something like this:

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source: Service Control Manager
Event Category: None
Event ID: 700X

The ServiceName service failed to start due to the following error:
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

A possible scenario is that your services are timing out during the Windows Server startup process, that is because your services might require more compute resources than it's available. After you are able to RDP to the machine, the Windows startup process has usually ended and then firing up the services manually works because you have enough cpu/memory to start it within the Time-out period.

Assuming this is the case for you, two possible solutions are:

1) Increase the Time-out value:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/922918/a-service-does-not-start-and-events-7000-and-7011-are-logged-in-window

2) Improve your VM specs